# Viewing HTTP POST requests send to local server

Tags: java, php, json

I'm sending JSON data from my Java application to my local webserver with my PHP script that is receiving this message. Now as far as I know I can only view what has been received by for example inserting the data in a database. Is there a way/application to view the live POST requests sent to my PHP webserver?

Comment: What have you tried? What isn't working? Do you know we are not here to write you a complete project?

Comment: Yes, I know. Like I said, I am simply putting it in the database to debug the data received, I was Googling around to find if there was an application that allows me to view the live HTTP request but no result.

Comment: Did you try [**fiddler**](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) ?

Comment: @adeneo With that I can not leave my webpage open send data and just view it right?

Comment: ALSO, are you aware of the differences between Javascript and Java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like to use [fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) for these kinds of tasks if the java HTTP library has support for proxies. Fiddler will list all information about the HTTP requests that is available. It will by default log all HTTP requests across your system, but can be told to limit to one application.

Comment: Fiddler indeed does exactly what I need! Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting your httpd logging level to verbose or (depending on what httpd it is) try to use extension that would do log all the data send in requests

Answer (score 0):

For debugging purposes why not just write the POST data to a file?

i.e.

```
file_put_contents(<some filename>, $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);
```